# QT QRegularExpression not matching

Tags: regex, qt

My code is:

```
QRegularExpression reg("^(.*) .*"); 
QString match = reg.match("help a").captured(1);
```

This should work and also checks out when I run it in an online regex testing website. Am I missing something?
Edit: I tried removing '^' from the pattern and it works.

Comment: Please provide a complete program illustrating the issue. As it stands, we don't know *how* you're establishing that it doesn't work. Specifically, `match` returns a `QRegularExpressionMatch` object which you need to query to see if it matched.

Comment: match is empty when I print or debug it. This is the entire piece that doesn't work, I tried by isolating it.

Comment: k.S, that's better, now we can see what the problem is :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no captured group `1` in that RE. Capture groups are indexed at zero so, if you want the `help`, you should be using:

```
QRegularExpression reg("^(.*) .*"); 
reg.match("help a").captured(0);
//                           ^
```

If you want the `a`, you should change the RE to capture it:

```
//                            v  v
QRegularExpression reg("^(.*) (.*)");   // "^.* (.*)" if you don't want 'help'
reg.match("help a").captured(1);        // 0          if you don't want 'help'
```

And, of course, you probably should be checking to make sure it matched before attempting to *use* any of those matches. This can be done with the `QRegularExpressionMatch::hasMatch()` function.

It *may* be that a better way to capture the first word (defined as any set of characters other than a space) is to explicitly allow for that:

```
^ *([^ ]*)
```

This will work better if you have multiple spaces following the first word, and also allow for spaces before the word.

Comment: I am actually trying to capture help but i can't manage to capture it without the trailing space. I tried a couple of things and forgot to change captured() index to 0. If you could please help.

Comment: @k.S, you won't capture the space unless it's inside the capture group or there is more than one space. If you want to *ensure* no trailing space, use `"^([^ ]*)"`. `[^ ]` is the character class "not space".